# Is this type family injective?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have type family for N-ary function from `n` arguments of type `t` to value of type `o`:

```
type family NAry (n :: Nat) (t :: Type) (o :: Type) = (r :: Type) | r -> n t o where
    NAry 1 t o = t -> o
    NAry n t o = t -> (NAry (n - 1) t o)
```

I think this family ought to be injective by I can't prove it to GHC:

```
error:
    * Type family equations violate injectivity annotation:
        NAry 1 t o = t -> o
        NAry n t o = t -> NAry (n - 1) t o
error:
    * Type family equation violates injectivity annotation.
      Type variable `n' cannot be inferred from the right-hand side.
      In the type family equation:
        NAry n t o = t -> NAry (n - 1) t o
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not as injective as you promise. Take the type

```
Int -> Int -> Bool
```

and ask: is this `NAry 2 Int Bool` or `NAry 1 Int (Int -> Bool)`?